# Sublime Text 3 - Add a pane at the bottom to my current layout

Tags: plugins, sublimetext3

I wanted to make a simple plugin for ST3 that adds a pane at the bottom of my screen with a simple key board shortcut. I am aware of [Origami](https://github.com/SublimeText/Origami), and TBH, would use it for a task like this, but I am doing this more out of getting a taste of making ST3 plugins.

NOTE: I do not want to change the layout. Whatever is there, add a pane at the bottom to it.

So for example, If my current screen tabs are arranged like this:

```
----------
| tab 1  |
|        |
----------
| tab 2  |
|        |
----------
```

Then I want to add a tab 3 so it is positioned like this:

```
----------
| tab 1  |
|        |
----------
| tab 2  |
----------
| tab 3  |
----------
```

Some more examples:

```
-----------------        ------------------
| tab 1 | tab 2 |        | tab 1  | tab 2 |
|       |       |        |        |       |
|       |       |  --- > ------------------ 
|       |       |        |      tab 3     |
-----------------        ------------------

-----------------        ------------------
| tab 1 | tab 2 |        | tab 1  | tab 2 |
|       |       |        |        |       |
-----------------  --- > ------------------
| tab 3 | tab 4 |        | tab 3  | tab 4 |
|       |       |        ------------------
-----------------        |    tab 5       |
                         ------------------
```

Here is the code I have so for:

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin
import subprocess

class CreateBottomTabCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        layout = self.window.get_layout()
        newLayout = calculate_new_layout_with_extra_pannel_at_bottom() # How do I do this?
        self.window.run_command("set_layout", newLayout)
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `window.get_layout()` returns an object like this:

```
{
    "cells": [[0,0,1,1],[1,0,2,2]],
    "cols": [0.0, 0.5, 1],
    "rows", [0.0, 1.0]
}
```

The `cells` attribute has a list of lists, where each inner list is the co-ordinate of that cell.

`cols` contains the relative Y position from (0 - 1) of each place to split the screen vertically at

`rows` is similar to `cols` but for horizontal breaks instead

To keep this brief I will reference you to the [docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/api.html#sublime.Window.set_layout) for more info.

So now, what we want to do, is insert your extra row in the middle of the last row and 1, (bottom of screen):

```
terminalPos = round(1 - ((1 - layout["rows"][-2]) / 2), 1)
```

We also want to give this it's cooridnates:

```
terminalCoords = [0, len(layout["rows"]) - 1 , len(layout["cols"]) - 1, len(layout["rows"])]
```

Then you can put these in the correct position the object, and presto! You're done!

Here is the full code:

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin
import subprocess

class CreateTerminalCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        layout = self.window.get_layout()

        terminalPos = round(1 - ((1 - layout["rows"][-2]) / 2), 1)
        terminalCoords = [0, len(layout["rows"]) - 1 , len(layout["cols"]) - 1, len(layout["rows"])]

        newLayout = layout
        newLayout["rows"].insert(-1, terminalPos)
        newLayout["cells"].append(terminalCoords)

        self.window.run_command("set_layout", newLayout)
```